# Where is Schedular.Dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I tring Rx(Reactive Extensions) for wpf and unable to find `Scheduler.Dispatcher`.
I did have added the reference of `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll` but even then I am unable to make it work...any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now `DispatcherScheduler.Instance`.